# In ANTLR3, why does the production "start : '(' ')' ;" match the string "())"?

Tags: antlr, context-free-grammar, antlr3

Switching to ANTLR4 is not a possible solution.

I'm writing a compiler for a custom language using ANTLR3, and it's not throwing errors on inputs such as `void main(){}}}}}}}}`. I have reduced the problem to a grammar as simple as:

```
grammar parens;

start   : '(' ')'
        ;

WS      : ( '\t' | ' ' | ('\r' | '\n') )+ { $channel = HIDDEN;}
        ;
```

I expect this grammar to match the input string "()" (with any arbitrary whitespace) however it seems to match the regular expression ()+ meaning () or ()) or ())) etc. I feel like I'm misunderstanding either CFGs or ANTLR at a low level causing this problem for me.

Comment: Disable its built-in recovery mechanism and also try to use not-greedy matching.

Comment: I'm not an ANTLR expert at all, I'm just using it for one class project. 
I found a solution that does not rely on those, but would you be able to briefly explain how those two features work or where I can find how they work? I'd like to try them to see if they work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much soulsearching I (read: a colleague) found a solution. By adding an EOF to the end of the production that is trying to match braces, it now accepts one and only one brace. In my large code this looks like:

```
program : function+ EOF
```

In the toy example it looks like:

```
grammar parens;

start   : '(' ')' EOF
        ;

WS      : ( '\t' | ' ' | ('\r' | '\n') )+ { $channel = HIDDEN;}
        ;
```